# "Ignore" option disabled in commit context menu

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Why is the "ignore" option disabled?

[image]

Comment: You can't ignore files that are already added to the version control, remove the file from VCS first, then you will be able to ignore it.

Comment: Anyone care to post an actual answer, or should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ignore files that are already added to the version control, remove the file from VCS first, then you will be able to ignore it.